# Small Java app performance

Tags: java, performance, processing-efficiency

I have a program for my CS class and i need to cut the runtime down by a lot when i get big inputs.

Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args){


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    int hours = 12;
    int minutes = 00;

    int count = 0;

    int d = input.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i < d; i++){
        minutes++;
        if(minutes >= 60){
            hours++;
            hours = hours % 12;
            minutes = 0;
        }

        String formatNull = "";
        String hourFormat = "";

        if(minutes < 10){
            formatNull = "0";
        }

        if(hours < 10)
            hourFormat = "0";

        String finalTimeString = hourFormat + hours + ":" + formatNull + minutes;

        if(isSequence(finalTimeString)){
            count += 1;

        }

    }

    System.out.println(count);

}

public static boolean isSequence(String time){

    String firstDig = time.split(":")[0];
    String secondDig = time.split(":")[1];



    ArrayList<Integer > foo = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if(firstDig.length() >= 2){
 if(firstDig.charAt(0) != '0'){
        foo.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(firstDig.charAt(0))));
    }   foo.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(firstDig.charAt(1))));
    }

    if(secondDig.length() >= 2){
        foo.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(secondDig.charAt(0))));
        foo.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(secondDig.charAt(1))));
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> bar = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int prev = foo.get(0);


    for(int i = 1; i < foo.size(); i++){


     bar.add(foo.get(i) - prev);
        prev = foo.get(i);
     }




    boolean isDiff = false;

    int prevDifference = bar.get(0);

    for(int i = 1; i < bar.size(); i++){
        if(prevDifference == bar.get(i)){

        }else{

            isDiff = true;

        }

        prevDifference = bar.get(i);

    }

    return !isDiff;

}
```

}

I can't get anything over 0.8 seconds and right now im hitting 2.0 seconds. If anyone could suggest anything it would be great. Cheers.

//update so i think i formatted the code properly now. This program takes an input in minutes, adds it to 12 o clock and counts how many special times there are. A special time is for example : 12:43, 02:46 (essentially a time where the digits have a common difference);

Comment: Hint: you expect us to spend our time to help you do your homework. So at least spend the time required to properly format / indent **all** of your input, and beyond that: explain what exactly your program is doing; and where you are stuck optimizing it. This here is **not** a free tutor service!

Comment: "If anyone could suggest anything..." That's the sort of question that's off-topic on SO. It's both too vague and also asks for a recommendation for an algorithm / strategy to fix. Both are off-topic

Comment: If your code is giving you the correct result and you're looking to improve it, it's probably better served on the (Code Review)[https://codereview.stackexchange.com/] website. But if you're looking for another algorithm, you should re-phrase your question.

Comment: @GhostCat One thing I've learned a long time ago (at least I tried) was: don't think about how others vote. Way too many users don't care about the purpose of this site ("high quality questions" *cough*) or just don't bother and upvote anything that has some english words and something formatted as code. That's why I'm hiding all votes using a custom css style. This site gets a bit better with that.

Comment: Thanks AntonH will do!

Comment: @user3551648 Folks on codereview will not be much happier when you put up such input there. We have "minimum standards" here and there. And your input doesn't meet those. Here and there. Period. So: turn back and study the [help] carefully to understand what to ask here (and the codereview folks have their own help center too)!

Comment: @AntonH codereview will not help. We have minimum standards that are expected from a question; and it doesn't matter if a bad question is put up here; or elsewhere; when it is not meeting the standards, it will not receive positive feedback.

Comment: @Tom Interesting approach; but well, I carefully select the questions I am answering to. And knowing its vote count is one part of making that decision.

Comment: @GhostCat Wouldn't the actual quality of the question (and the fact that it isn't a duplicate (very important for me)) be a much better indicator for that than the info what others think about the question?

Comment: " A special time is for example : 12:43" - If you call `isSequence("12:43")` it returns false.  Perhaps before you worry about efficiency, you should make sure it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I notice right away:

First, you're calling `isSequence` in a loop. `isSequence` itself has two loops. Thus, this algorithm is `O(d * (foo.size() + bar.size())`. In fact, we could actually say that it's `Theta(d * (foo.size() + bar.size())` (i.e. always exactly that complexity) since there's not really a possibility of it taking fewer than `d * (foo.size() + bar.size())` steps. (For the record, yes, I do realize that I'm not being strictly accurate with the notation because multiples of *n* just reduce to *n*, but I think writing it out that way is useful). This is probably one of the major reasons it's slow for large inputs. You may want to think about ways to try to reduce that.

My point in mentioning that is that there's only so much you can do in terms of code optimization if your underlying algorithm's computational complexity is too high.

Secondly, as an optimization:

```
for(int i = 1; i < bar.size(); i++){
    if(prevDifference == bar.get(i)){
       // You don't actually do anything here
    }else{
        // Why not break out the loop here? There's no possibility of this
        // becoming false later. That could save you some steps.
        isDiff = true;
    }

    prevDifference = bar.get(i);
}
```

Finally, why can't you combine your for loops in `isSequence`?

Comment: Foo and bar are tiny, I think.  4 at most.  So the gains from this will be tiny as well.  (But that doesn't mean they shouldn't be implemented.)

Comment: @DM Yes, I think you're correct. But even if they're both 4, that would still be `8d` operations.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:  As far as I can tell, your code is currently giving the wrong answer.  You need to fix that.  But you asked about how to make it run faster, not how to fix it, so that's what I'm answering.

You're doing a lot of String formatting and parsing, and a lot of it is in your main loop.  How many times are you going from String to int and int to String?  All that converting back and forth is slowing things down significantly.

If your minutes are 2 digits, you can get the last digit with `minutes % 10`.  You can get the first digit with `minutes / 10`.  Same thing with the hours.  No String parsing required.  This is already enough to take the time down below what is required.

But there's something else you can do that's even better.  Instead of having your code run in O(n) time, you can make it run in what is effectively O(1) time.  Yes, you read that correctly.  For large n, you can make this run in constant time.

Note that there are only so many possible combinations of hours and minutes in a day.  If you're using 12 hour time, then 12*60 = 720.  You can take advantage of this.  All you need to process is the answer for 720, and the answer for `n % 720`, and then do a little math.  `answer(n)` is `answer(720) * n/720 + answer(n % 720)`.  Using this, you can more or less instantly calculate any value up to 2147483647.  Heck, if you used long instead of int, you could more or less instantly calculate any value up to 9223372036854775807.  (Think about it - the answer for 72000000 is going to be exactly 100000 times the answer for 720, because the same numbers are just repeating, so why bother looping 72000000 times?)